# Stack Exchange site for asking questions about how to do something?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, asking-questions, new-questions

Please suggest a Stack Exchange site where I can ask questions such as:

- How do I install the Sublime Text editor from tar.bz2?
- How do I run multiple commands at once in a Linux terminal?

I wish to ask technical questions which are not directly related to programming, these types of questions are outside the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: The answers are correct but both questions are already asked: https://askubuntu.com/questions/172698/how-do-i-install-sublime-text-2-3 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130847/running-multiple-commands-in-one-line-in-shell

Comment: My case was different, I tried those ways but it didn't work for me. Thats why asked them with screenshots in stackoverflow but I got downvote for my questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of your questions would be on-topic if you posted them on the right site and phrased them correctly.

Either question would be appropriate for [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) (if you're using Ubuntu) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/). The first question would probably be fine for any of the sites, but the second would be better suited for Unix and Linux/Ask Ubuntu.

However, after a quick Google search, I found that your first question had already been answered on AskUbuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/227617/508087). Scroll to the 'Install manually via the terminal' section to find your answer. (Note: since you've already downloaded the file, you won't need to `wget` it - simply navigate to the correct directory and use the correct filename)

The second question would also be better if you were more specific. What do you mean by 'run multiple commands at once in the terminal'? Do you want to type them all at once so that they will automatically run in the right order after you press enter, or do you want to have them run simultaneously? Make sure that you specify *exactly* what you want and what you have already tried/searched.

And finally, no matter where you post, make sure that you use correct English grammar and punctuation (capitalising first letter of each sentence, capital I not `i`). This will make your post look more professional.

Answer (score 4):

There's a [Linux & Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) site. Its [help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says that Shell scripting is on-topic which would appear to cover running multiple commands in a linux terminal.

It has a [terminal](/questions/tagged/terminal) tag and a [software-installation](/questions/tagged/software-installation) tag. As always check the help centre yourself and search for duplicates before posting.